# Convert raster to im object

Tags: raster, spatstat

I would like to convert a raster to an im object but have so far been unable to do so.

Here is a reproducible example:

Create raster layer and add data to it:

```
r.toy <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r.toy[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r.toy))
```

Plot the raster:

```
plot(r.toy)
```

[image: raster]

Convert to image:

```
r.toy.im <- as.im(r.toy)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in as.im.default(r.toy) : Can't convert X to a pixel image
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to load the maptools package which can convert many spatial
formats in R:

```r
library(raster)
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
r.toy <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r.toy[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r.toy))
r.toy.im <- as.im(r.toy)
plot(r.toy.im)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that maptools had to be loaded! However, I just tried to do the same thing, this time converting a polygon into an im object and received the same error message, despite maptools being loaded. Is polygon not a suitable data type to be converted to im?

Comment: Correct. Polygon should be converted to `owin`.